# How can I get the row, column clicked in shiny flextable?

Tags: r, shiny, flextable

How can I get the row, column clicked in shiny flextable? Like in dataTable?

```
library(shiny)
library(flextable)

ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput("flexReport")
)

server <- function(input, output, server) {
    output$flexReport <- renderUI({
        ft <- flextable(mtcars)
        ft <- htmltools_value(ft, ft.align = "left")
        ft
    })
    observe({
        ###  print(input$flexReport_cells_selected)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I don't see any reference to registering clicks in the package documentation. Is there something that suggests this feature? (I know that `DT` supports clicks, not sure which if any other packages do.)

Comment: as noted by @r2evans there is no feature like this. flextable targets only static tabular reporting